# jQuery find whole number and append decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, numeric

Need to take a SELECT drop down list options and find if any of the values are whole numbers, then append a .00 to the list value option. need to change the value as well.

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1.99">1.99</option>
  <option value="2.99">2.99</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: This really isn't much of JQuery question, its just standard javascript.  JQuery can be used for easily extracting the values from the select box, but it has nothing to do with the calculation.

Comment: Not really sure what you were doing, but the 2nd solution doesn't round up the numbers... at least not with the data you have up there...

Comment: I just need to append the .00 if the number is a whole number 0-9 no need to round the number either. Thanks!

Comment: That is what my example is doing, though. I'm not sure where you got that it rounds the numbers. Did you click on the demo link I posted? http://jsbin.com/ayumi - it keeps 1.99 and 2.99 as is, but adds .00 to 1 and 4. isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not *quite* sure if this is the best way, but it works:

```
$('option', '#myselect').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == parseInt($(this).val(), 10)) {
         var x = $(this).val() + '.00';
         $(this).val(x).text(x);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ekafa).

On second thought, you could also do this using [`toFixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp), which is cleaner:

```
$('option', '#myselect').each(function() {
    var x = Number($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(x).text(x);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ayumi).

Comment: I like the first solution but not working on page reload when values are populated from database

Comment: BTW I looked into your second solution and it seems to round up the number. Just wanted to clarify if that's the case?

Comment: How do I use this for two and three digit numbers? 10 needs to be 10.00 and 100 needs to be 100.00

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using string formatting a lot, i recommend getting the plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/StringFormat

It would then be as easy as:
    $.format('{a:.2f}', {a:'1'})